# How to pronounce "R → ∞ " in a mathematical context

Tags: readings, mathematics, symbols

For example on [this wikipedia page](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%95%99%E6%95%B0#.E7.95.99.E6.95.B0.E5.AE.9A.E7.90.86):

> 一方、右辺第二項は R → ∞ のとき 0 に収束するので、...

In English it would be something like "as R goes to infinity".
How would you usually read this in Japanese?

Comment: From [this](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30843/3275) answer: [数式記号の読み方・表し方](http://izumi-math.jp/sanae/report/suusiki/suusiki.htm).

Comment: It's perfectly okay to ask questions of this nature on Japanese.SE :-)

Comment: We need some word to express this.

Comment: 俗には "R を無限大に飛ばすとき"  という言い方もありますね．

Comment: I participate in math stack exchange, english and japanese wiki.I can say mathematical expression are almost same all over the world.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> R → ∞

is usually read

> R を限りなく大きくする［と・とき］
>   R が限りなく大きくなる［と・とき］

I don't think that 「R → ∞ **のとき**」 is supposed to have a fixed natural pronunciation. You can ignore the の and read it as above, or you could probably read it as

> [R]{アール} [→]{トゥ} [∞]{インフィニティ} のとき
>   [R]{アール} [→]{ツー} [∞]{インフィニティ} のとき

Comment: +1 for a mathematician on this site.  :)  It's interesting that the wikipedia page on limits [極限](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%A5%B5%E9%99%90) does not explain how to read the notation while the English version does.  Hmmm.  Though you could perhaps infer it from the context.

Answer (score 5):

In Japanese,

- R is pronounced *aaru* (アール)
- → is pronounced *yajirusi* (矢印【やじるし】)
- ∞ is pronounced *mugendai* (無限大【むげんだい】)

I think "n→∞" is often pronounced as follows in the differential and integral.

- エヌ矢印無限大 *enu yajirusi mugendai*
- エヌ無限大 *enu mugendai*

where *enu* (エヌ) means the letter N.

Therefore I guess that "R→∞" is pronounced in the same way.

Although, because it is terminology, I guess it does not have a clear colloquial pronunciation.

It seems that there are some people who call it *aaru twu infinithi* (R to infinity) in Japanese English.